# Departure Date after Arrival Date

Tags: sql, date

This is probably a simple answer but I don't know it, how do I make sure the Departure is after the Arrival date.

Thanks

Wayne

```
DATEADD(day, ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 365), '1 Jan 2010') as ArrivalDate,
DATEADD(day, ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 365), '1 Jan 2010') as DepatureDate,
```

Comment: What do you mean by make sure?  Do you want to prevent inserting records where that condition is not met?  Do you want to exclude the results which don't meet the condition?  Do you want the query to use the later of Departure and Arrival date?

Comment: Add more days to DepartureDate than you add to ArrivalDate.  You should probaly *also* have a CHECK constraint on the base table.

Comment: Hi Marlin/Catcall
If I Arrive 01/01/2010 the departure date can only be => 02/01/2010, so when the number is randomly generated it will only do this.

Comment: @Catcall - your comment should be an answer. You may add an example of check constraint.

Comment: @Art: I know. I didn't have time to flesh it out this morning. (Or now.) Feel free to write it up yourself, if you want to.

Answer (score 1):

You can check by using `DATEDIFF ('day', DepatureDate, ArrivalDate)`.

This way you can subtract the ArrivalDate from the DepatureDate. If you get a negative answer, then DepatureDate is before the ArrivalDate.

Have a look at this link:

[DATEDIFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)

EDIT:

```
DECLARE @var1 int;
DECLARE @var2 int;
SET @var1 = ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 365);
SET @var2 = ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % (365-@var1));
select @var1, @var2, DATEADD(day, @var1, '1 Jan 2010') as ArrivalDate, DATEADD(day, @var2, DATEADD(day, @var1, '1 Jan 2010')) as DepatureDate
```

Comment: Hi Wessel

I understand Datediff, but can you use when you are randomly generating departure dates?

Comment: Ah I see what you want, try playing around with setting variables. This code seemed to work quite well: see my answer

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to use a `case` statement:

```
(case when ArrivalDate < DepartureDate then 1 else 0 end) as IsArrivalBefore
```

This also has the advantage of being standard syntax and understood by almost all databases.  (Your question does not mention the database you are using.)